# Windows Server 2019 Cannot Install .NET 3.5

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019, .net, dism, .net-3.5

[crosspost](/questions/tagged/crosspost) [Microsoft IT Pro Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/windows-server-2019-cannot-install-net-3-5/m-p/3853113/highlight/true#M9994)

[crosspost](/questions/tagged/crosspost) [r/sysadmin](https://old.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/14ffj8q/windows_server_2019_cannot_install_net_35/?ref=share&ref_source=link)

---

## Windows Server 2019 Cannot Install .NET 3.5

I am running Windows Server 2019 (Version 1809, Build 17763.4499) and I cannot install .NET Framework 3.5. Below is the current installation status of the feature on my machine:

```pwsh
PS > Get-WindowsFeature -Name  NET-Framework-Features,NET-Framework-Core,NET-HTTP-Activation,NET-Non-HTTP-Activ

Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[X] .NET Framework 3.5 Features                         NET-Framework-Features         Installed
    [ ] .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)  NET-Framework-Core               Removed
    [ ] HTTP Activation                                 NET-HTTP-Activation              Removed
    [ ] Non-HTTP Activation                             NET-Non-HTTP-Activ               Removed
```

Through hours of searching online I have not been able to discover a resolution to the issue I am seeing. I followed the installation steps in [How to Install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 11/10 and Windows Server (Windows OS Hub)](https://woshub.com/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-on-windows/) as this was the most complete guide. None of the suggested installation methods worked.

> 1. Via Server Manager: Add roles and features -> Features -> .NET
>    Framework 3.5 Features -> .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and
>    3.0 )
> 2. Using DISM: `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All`
>
>    - Using DISM: `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess`
> 3. With PowerShell: `Install-WindowsFeature -Name NET-Framework-Core`
>
>    - With PowerShell: `Install-WindowsFeature -Name NET-Framework-Core -Source D:\Sources\SxS`
> 4. With DISM:`DISM /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:D:\Sources\SxS\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab`

I also tried using the offline packages from my installation media without success. And when trying to use GPO to force installation from / prohibit installation from Windows Update (non-WSUS) I did not see any results.

Regardless which method I use, I end up getting the same `0x800f0800` error. I've only come across [one other user who has received the same error code when trying to install a Windows feature](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5be0b03c-f499-4530-837d-76eacb4f1473/net-framework-35-cannot-install), but their resolution was just rebuilding their server. This is not a viable option for my scenario. The full error from PowerShell is displayed below:

```pwsh
PS> Install-WindowsFeature -Name NET-Framework-Core -Source D:\Sources\SxS

Install-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. Error: 0x800f0800
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-WindowsFeature -Name NET-Framework-Core -Source D:\Sources\SxS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature],
    Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand
```

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will need to check the file C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log for errors.  Sounds like something that would be damaged when a language pack is present/removed from a system.  Check this registry key for the presence of other locales: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackageDetect\

Answer (score 0):

try
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3ServerFeatures /Source:d:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

Comment: Please  format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability. Additionally some context about what that command/code is supposed to do is highly recommended.